# dynamic range within collection errors

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to copy all unique values from the range in the tab as defined below, to a single column in the "Summary" tab:

```vb
Sub GetUniqueItems()
    Dim vData As Variant, n&, lLastRow&, sMsg$
    Dim oColl As Collection

    lLastRow = Worksheets(Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1").Value)._
    Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    If lLastRow = 1 Then Exit Sub

    vData = Worksheets(Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1").Value)._
    Range("H2:H" & lLastRow)
    Set oColl = New Collection
    For n = LBound(vData) To UBound(vData)
        On Error Resume Next
        oColl.Add vData(n, 1), CStr(vData(n, 1))
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next n

    For n = 1 To oColl.Count
        sMsg = oColl(n)
        Sheets("Summary").Cells(n + 3, 1).Value = Mid$(sMsg, 1)
    Next n
End Sub
```

This works great for the defined range. What I want to do though is copy from a dynamic range from the defined tab. This range will be defined by the last column with an entry in row 1 and the last filled row between column A and the last column. It seems though that as soon as I introduce a lastcol variable, or a range that includes multiple columns the code brings up an error.

The code as I have built so far is:

```vb
Sub GetUniqueItems()
    Dim vData As Variant, n&, lLastRow&, sMsg$
    Dim oColl As Collection

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lLastCol As Long

    'Find last column in Row 1 of each data tab
    lLastCol = Worksheets(Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1").value)._
    Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    If lLastCol < 1 Then Exit Sub

    ' Find the last row of the last column
    lLastRow = Worksheets(Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1").value)._
    Cells(Rows.Count, lLastCol).End(xlUp).Row

    If lLastRow = 1 Then Exit Sub

    vData = Worksheets(Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1").value).Range(llastcol)

    Set oColl = New Collection
    For n = LBound(vData) To UBound(vData)
        If Not (IsDate(vData(n, 1)) Or IsEmpty(vData(n, 1))) Then oColl._
    Add (vData(n, 1)), CStr(vData(n, 1))
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next n

    For n = 1 To oColl.Count
        sMsg = oColl(n)

        Sheets("Summary").Cells(n + 3, 1).value = Mid$(sMsg, 1)
        Sheets("Summary").Cells(n + 3, 1).Offset(0, 1).value = _
        Application.CountIf(Worksheets(Range(Split(Sheets("Summary")._
    Cells(n + 3, 1).Address, "$")(1) & "1").value).Cells, Mid$(sMsg, 1))
    Next n

End Sub
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The error I get is due to `.Range(lLastCol)`, where `lLastCol` is an integer.

If you want to select the column with that index, use `.Columns(lLastCol)` instead.

The next error I ran into was due to the fact that I was trying to add duplicates to `oColl`. I used the same trick as in your first sample so overcome this and got past the error.

The next error is somewhere in the last line of code before the last `Next n`. There's probably an off-by-one or some logic error, but I'll trust you can take it from here.

My code:

```vb
Sub GetUniqueItems_Dynamic()
    Dim vData As Variant, n&, lLastRow&, sMsg$
    Dim oColl As Collection

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lLastCol As Long

    'Find last column in Row 1 of each data tab
    lLastCol = Worksheets(Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1").Value). _
    Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    If lLastCol < 1 Then Exit Sub

    ' Find the last row of the last column
    lLastRow = Worksheets(Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1").Value). _
    Cells(Rows.Count, lLastCol).End(xlUp).Row

    If lLastRow = 1 Then Exit Sub

    vData = Worksheets(Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1").Value).Columns(lLastCol)

    Set oColl = New Collection
    For n = LBound(vData) To UBound(vData)
        On Error Resume Next
        If Not (IsDate(vData(n, 1)) Or IsEmpty(vData(n, 1))) Then oColl. _
    Add (vData(n, 1)), CStr(vData(n, 1))
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next n

    For n = 1 To oColl.Count
        sMsg = oColl(n)

        Sheets("Summary").Cells(n + 3, 1).Value = Mid$(sMsg, 1)
        Sheets("Summary").Cells(n + 3, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value = _
            Application.CountIf(Worksheets(Range(Split(Sheets("Summary"). _
            Cells(n + 3, 1).Address, "$")(1) & "1").Value).Cells, Mid$(sMsg, 1))
    Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: W0lf,thank you very much. I have fixed the rest, but this still accepts the range as a single column only. If I try to add more than one column, it generates an Error 1004. I have tried .Columns(1, lLastCol) and .Columns(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, lLastCol))

Comment: Or even more oddly, exports only data from the first column when a static range is explicitly defined (i.e. exports values from "A" only with code .Columns("A:H"))

Comment: @MarioKonfortov can you please post a short example of what you are trying to achieve in the question? Maybe two screenshots: the input sheet and the output (correctly populated)

Comment: Thanks @W0lf. What I want to start with is: [link](http://imgur.com/oLiwH8N)[/link]. What I want to generate is: [link](http://imgur.com/ZpuQhOw)[/link]. I want all columns from each input tab to be amalgamated into a single column with number of occurrences of each (coded already). Thanks for the help again!

Comment: @MarioKonfortov OK, `.Columns(1, lastCol)` is not supported; it only takes on parameter. This means that a possible solution would be to have an outer `For` loop that iterates from 1 to `lastCol` and for each iteration, process one of the columns as you are doing now for the last one.

Comment: @MarioKonfortov I don't have Excel, so I cannot test the code, but hopefully this will work.